# Как парсить CSS? (php)

Tags: php, css, регулярные-выражения

Нужно превратить строку правил цсс (т.е. значение аттрибута `style=""`) в массив формата `['rule'=>'value']`.

`explode(';',$style)` не предлагать, потому что:

```
background-image: url("data:image/gif;base64,...
```

Comment: Вот это `style=""` вы имеете в виду из html кода css выдрать и получить массив, а не из файла стилей?

Comment: Селекторы не нужны. Медиа не нужно. Нужно только строки вида rule1:value1[;rule2:value2[;...]]. Не вычленять их из хтмл-страницы. Все уже найдено, нужно только распарсить. Без проверки на валидность.

Comment: Есть некое [существующее решение](https://github.com/sabberworm/PHP-CSS-Parser), смотрели?

Comment: существующее решение, это хорошо... однако интересно было бы самому сделать. Мне вот интересно стало!... А кто знает, где еще, кроме `url()` и `content` может использоваться точка-с-запятой? Может конкретно для этих двоих какое-то исключение сделать... тогда и `explode()` сработает...

Comment: @cyadvert, хех, натолкнул на мысль. 1) заменить через preg_replace точку с запятой в конструкциях типа url(base64) на что-то без нее; 2) разделить explod-ом; 3) вернуть обратно точку с запятой через то же preg_replace. Надо протестить.

Comment: @cyadvert по [ссылке](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#tokenization), начиная с `declaration : property S* ':' S* value;` описаны все варианты `value`.

Comment: @kanaris ну я так и думал, просто надо было убедиться, где еще точка-с-запятой пользуется... Когда заработает, ответ сделаете? спасибо

Comment: @cyadvert, ок, если не забуду. Надо ж поискать варианты с ";" еще.

Answer (score 1):

@cyadvert, cобственно решение оформил так:

```
<?php

$css=file_get_contents('css.css');

$raw=array_map(function($v){
    return preg_replace_callback(
        '~url\(\s*(?:"|\')data:[a-z-]+/[a-z-]+@base64~is',
        function($m){return str_replace('@',';',$m[0]);},
        $v
    );
},explode(
    ';',
    preg_replace_callback(
        '~url\(\s*(?:"|\')data:[a-z-]+/[a-z-]+;base64~is',
        function($m){return str_replace(';','@',$m[0]);},
        $css
    )
));
$rules=[];
foreach($raw as $v){
    $s=explode(':',$v,2);
    $rules[trim(strtolower($s[0]))]=trim($s[1]);
}

echo '<pre>'.print_r($rules,1).'</pre>';

?>
```

Вроде работает. Пока ";" учитывается только в base64-урле. `content` добавлять не было смысла, т.к. в аттрибутах `style` оно в принципе не используется. Также не учитывалось `font`(`-family`), т.к. шрифтов с ";" я пока не встречал. Если встречу еще распространенные случаи, добавить не сложно.

Comment: Спасибо... Интересно... Пойду шефу подсуну - скажу "сам написал" :)

Comment: Может быть проще игнорировать те **:**, которые находятся внутри **"..."** ?

Answer (score 1):

Можете попробовать такую регулярку:

```
/\b([-a-z]+)\s*:\s((?:(?:\(.*?\))*|(?:\'.*?\')*|(?:\".*?\")*|.)*?)\s*;/gs
```

Пример работы https://regex101.com/r/fS8uR4/2

Пример использование в php:

```
$css =   'font-family: \'roboto\';
          src: local(\'roboto\'), url(\'data:application/x-font-woff;base64,d09GRgABAAAAAGC...\') format(\'woff\');
          font-weight: 400;
          font-style: normal;
        quotes: \'"\' \'"\' "\'" "\'";
         content: url(\'data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="32" height="32"><path d="M19.414 27.414l10-10c0.781-0.781 0.781-2.047 0-2.828l-10-10c-0.781-0.781-2.047-0.781-2.828 0-0.781 0.781-0.781 2.047 0 2.828l6.586 6.586h-19.172c-1.105 0-2 0.895-2 2s0.895 2 2 2h19.172l-6.586 6.586c-0.39 0.39-0.586 0.902-0.586 1.414s0.195 1.024 0.586 1.414c0.781 0.781 2.047 0.781 2.828 0z" fill="#FFF" /></svg>\');
        ';

$reg = '/\b([-a-z]+)\s*:\s((?:(?:\(.*?\))*|(?:\'.*?\')*|(?:\".*?\")*|.)*?)\s*;/s';
preg_match_all($reg, $css, $matches);

$result = array_combine($matches[1], $matches[2]);

echo "<pre>\n";
var_dump($result);
echo "</pre>\n";
```

Результат:

```
array(6) {
  ["font-family"]=> string(8) "'roboto'"
  ["src"]=> string(93) "local('roboto'), url('data:application/x-font-woff;base64,d09GRgABAAAAAGC...') format('woff')"
  ["font-weight"]=> string(3) "400"
  ["font-style"]=> string(6) "normal"
  ["quotes"]=>  string(15) "'"' '"' "'" "'""
  ["content"]=> string(414) "url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,')"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Наверное самым правильным методом было бы взять [грамматику](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/grammar.html) CSS и построить для нее парсер (например с помощью [Jison](http://zaach.github.io/jison/)). В вашем случае нужен символ `ruleset`, а точнее его часть `S* declaration? [ ';' S* declaration? ]*`.